# Extracting values from a list without regex

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

Having a list containing values with special characters in between:

```
myLst = ['5-8','20130-23199','1025-2737']
```

How do you extract the values with the `-` in between, without using regex?

I "solved" this with regex but it is very slow with huge numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split),

```
myLst = ['5-8','20130-23199','1025-2737']

result = [s.split('-') for s in myLst]

print(result)
#[['5', '8'], ['20130', '23199'], ['1025', '2737']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with range()

```
for i in myLst:
  tmp = i.split("-")
  print(list(range(int(tmp[0])+1,int(tmp[1]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myLst = ['5-8','20130-23199','1025-2737']
```

result = []

[result.extend([s.split('-')[0],s.split('-')[1]]) for s in myLst]

print result